# mongo wire protocol: value of responseTo in client request packet

Tags: mongodb

What should be the value of `responseTo` of `MsgHeader` of mongo [Standard Message Header](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#standard-message-header) when a client sends a packet to the server? Is it anything random or 0?

In mongo wire protocol [specification](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#standard-message-header), I didn't find the value of it in case of client forming the `MsgHeader`, though it only says:

> // requestID from the original request
> //   (used in responses from db)

But, when I dump the network packets, I see the value is `0`.

Comment: why do you need this? It's completely internal impl details

Comment: I am working on a mongo proxy where I need this. If this value is something deterministic I could use this to determine the direction of a packet without much computation and memory.

Comment: as I recall, `responseTo` should be equal to `requestId`, but there are enough internal logic and rules behind this, so I would not rely on this anywhere outside

Comment: You missed my question, I said when client sends the request.